# How to create a Thread for each person of the arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an arraylist of person `ArrayList<Person>`. Each person get it's name and age in random. In that `ArrayList` of `Person` I filtered out those age 18 using a lambda expression.

My question is how can I create a `Thread` for each filtered `Person` of the `Arraylist`.

My code:

```
public class Person implements Runnable
{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void run() {
        // to fill up later
    }
}

public class Main {
        private static int nameCount = 1;
        public static List<Person> list;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            list = new ArrayList<Person>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                list.add(new Person(getPersonName(), getPersonAge());
            }
            list.removeIf(p -> p.getage().equals(18));
            for (Person person : list) {
                System.out.println(persion);
            } 
        }

        public static String getPersonName() {
            String nameto = "PERSON" + String.valueOf(nameCount);
            nameCount++;
            return nameto;
        }

        public static int getPersonAge() {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int ageperson = ran.nextInt(25) + 1;
            return ageperson;
        }
        //how to make an instance of Thread after filtering the person
    }
```

Comment: Code in form of a picture is generally not very well received on SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Following @TimoSta suggestion, please edit your question and copy/paste your code instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: The idea of `Person implements Runnable` sounds very strange.  What does it mean to "run" a person?  What will it mean when there is more than one thing that you might want to do to a person in a background thread?

Comment: Could you explain a reason why do you want to create a separate thread for each person ? Creating a thread is very expensive operation, creating 1000 threads for 1000 persons doesn't speed your application up, it rather extremely slows it down.

Comment: our activity in school about threads. I need to create a race of person like a marathon. each person needs to have a thread.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James Large that the idea of `Person implements Runnable` sounds very strange.

But any way to implement some logic for each item in the list You can use StreamAPI and method `foreach`, I also recommend to use method `filter`

So the result will be the next:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getage() == 18)
    .forEach(person -> new Thread(person).start());
```

Comment: do I need to enclose this in a loop? to create a thread for each person?

Comment: No, You don't need, 
Method `forEach()` invoke the logic for each element in the stream.
So in your case for each element will be created a thread and invoked method `start()`.